# How to interpret predict_proba() when predicting one class?

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn

When we try to predict a test set that contains just one class, the`.predict_proba()` method returns a 2D array with 2 columns instead of 1. My guess is that it represents the probability of belonging/not belonging to the class. I would like to confirm this since documentation wasn't clear enough about this case.

Looking a little further in source code, I found this:

```py
if y_pred.ndim == 1:
   return np.vstack([1 - y_pred, y_pred]).T
```

but I still cannot interpret if index 0 means belonging to the class or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: index `0`, as source code suggests, predicts **not belonging** (ie `1-y_pred`), assuming `y_pred` predicts **belonging**

Comment: That's odd. I've made [this example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gbZodCQP9v9sWofqrubfvf8XqIdYeS23?usp=sharing), note that the model is being trained with just one class and the highest probabilities are always in index 0. In theory, if a model is trained with just one class, every test case will be labeled as that class.